# How are user sessions/data stored on web servers?

Tags: session, architecture, operating-system, webserver

I'm just starting to get into web development in earnest, more than just static pages, and I keep wondering, how is data stored per user on the server? When one user submits a form post, and it gets looked up on another page, how can the server tell user1's FooForm data from user2's FooForm data? I know you can keep track of users with cookies and HTTP requests, but how does the server keep all these data sets available? Is there like a tiny virtual machine for each user session? Or some kind of paging system where the user's content is served, and then the server swaps that process out for a while like a system thread? I've always wondered how a site with a million concurrent visitors manages to serve them all and keep all the individual user sessions contained.

I'm familiar with OS multithreaded architecture and algorithms, but the idea of doing that with anywhere from one to a million separate "threads" on a anywhere from one to n separate machines is mind blowing.

Do the algorithms change as the scale does?

I'll stop before I ask too many questions and this gets too broad, but I'd love for someone with some expertise to elucidate this for me, or point me to a good resource.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Normally, if you are storing more than just a few values, the entire data set is held in a database.  It would be impossibly inefficient to hold a million users' information in memory indefinitely.

Comment: But what about for anonymous users, or data that's only relevant for a couple minutes until the user completes their objective or whatever? That sort of stuff that doesn't get saved to databases has to be somewhere, yeah?

Comment: Sure it does.  I used to work for an online retialer that did exactly that.  If the user didn't have an account, a temporary record was created to track their session.